# Finding all values of $a$ such that the system $x^2+y=2x+a$, $x^2+y^2=2x$ has solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> Find all values of $a$ such that this system of equation has solutions
> \begin{align}
> x^{2}+y\phantom{^2} &=2 x+a \\
> x^{2}+y^{2}&=2 x
> \end{align}

I tried to substitute second equation into the first one, I managed to make a quadratic equation and I got that $a$ must be less or equal to $1/4$.

but the correct answer is $[-2;1/4]$

I also graphed that and I could see that the minimum value of is actually -2 but how to prove this? What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different approach for the sake of curiosity.

According to the second equation, we have that
\begin{align*}
x^{2} + y^{2} = 2x & \Longleftrightarrow (x - 1)^{2} + y^{2} = 1
\end{align*}

So the solutions must belong to the corresponding circle.

On the other hand, the first equation reduces to
\begin{align*}
y = -(x - 1)^{2} + 1 + a
\end{align*}

which is the parabola $y = -(x - 1)^{2}$ translated by $1 + a$.

If $1 + a \geq -1$, then the proposed parabola does not touch the circle.

Hence we conclude that $1 + a \geq -1$.

Now it remains to find the other bound for $a$.

In order to find the upper bound for $a$, we are interested in determining for which values of it such that the parabola still touches the circle. This corresponds to find out the the maximum value of $a$ such that the next inequation holds:

\begin{align*}
-(x - 1)^{2} + 1 + a  \leq \sqrt{1 - (x - 1)^{2}} & \Longleftrightarrow 1 + a \leq \sqrt{1 - (x - 1)^{2}} + (x - 1)^{2}
\end{align*}

Once the maximum of the RHS is given by $5/4$, the other bound for $a$ is given by $1 + a \leq 5/4$, that is to say, $a \leq 1/4$.

Hence the desired solution is given by $a\in[-2,1/4]$.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the first from the second equation:

$$y^2-y=-a$$
$$y^2-y+a=0$$
$$y=\frac12\pm\sqrt{\frac14-a}$$

If a is bigger than $\frac14$ than the term inside the root is negative which would leave you with no real solutions. So the upper bound for a is: $a<\frac14$.

When you plug this representation of y into equation 2:

$$x^2+{\left(\frac12\pm\sqrt{\frac14-a}\right)}^2=2x$$
$$x=\sqrt{a\pm\frac12\sqrt{1-4a}+\frac12}\mp1$$

And now you solve the unequality:

$$a\pm\frac12\sqrt{1-4a}+\frac12>0$$
$$a>-2$$

And you have your lower bound. Now you can put them together to get $-2<a<0.25$.